# ocg-p: Optional Content Groups in LuaTeX

Tags: ocg-p

- I want to use the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) in a document.
- The document should be compiled with `luatex`.
- It seems as if the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) only works with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.
- **Q:** Is there a package similar to the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) that works with `luatex`?

[image]

*(CTAN screenshot)*

---

[image]

*(Overleaf settings)*

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ocg-p}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}

\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}
```

*(MWE)*

---

> ```
> l.30   \ifnum\pdftexversion
>                          <120
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
> <to be read again> 
> <
> l.30   \ifnum\pdftexversion<
>                           120
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
> (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
> look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
> ```

*(Error message)*

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me... the [ocgx2 package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) does precisely that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ocgx2} % <-- Modified!

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}

\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]