# Using ocgx2 instead of ocg-p: \AddToShipoutPictureBG not recognized

Tags: ocgx2, ocg-p

- I want to use the [ocgx2 package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) under `luatex`.
- In the past, I used the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) but the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) does not work with `luatex`, see [ocg-p: Optional Content Groups in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676336).
- My (apparently wrong) understanding is, that the [ocgx2 package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) is code-compatible with the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p).
- **Problem:** The below code works fine with the [ocg-p package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) under `pdflatex` but does not work with the [ocgx2 package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) under `luatex`.

> ```
> l.19 \AddToShipoutPictureBG
>                            
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{ocgx2} % Works not fine under luatex
\usepackage{ocg-p} % Works fine under pdflatex

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276532
\AddToShipoutPictureBG
{\begin{ocg}[printocg = never]{PDF Navigation Elements}{oc1}{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor = west, font = \large, align = left] () at (current page.west){\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\faArrowAltCircleLeft}\\\Acrobatmenu{GoForward}{\faArrowAltCircleRight}};    
    \end{tikzpicture}   
 \end{ocg}%
 }

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` is defined in pkg `eso-pic` which seems to be a dependency of `ocg-p`. I would use the hook facilities built into the LaTeX kernel instead. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Kernel-builtin hook facilities (available since 1/10/2020), everything works fine across all engines:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} 
 
\usepackage{fontawesome5} 
 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{ocgx2} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
 
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{% 
  \setlength\unitlength{\paperheight}% 
  \begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{PDF Navigation Elements}{oc1}{on} 
  \hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}% 
  \large% 
  \put(0,-0.5){% 
    \tikz\node[inner sep=2pt]{\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\faArrowAltCircleLeft}}; 
  }% 
  \put(0,-0.5){% 
    \raisebox{-\height}{\tikz\node[inner sep=2pt]{\Acrobatmenu{GoForward}{\faArrowAltCircleRight}};} 
  }% 
  \end{ocg}% 
} 
 
\begin{document} 
Test 
\end{document}
```

The spacing between the buttons can be adjusted with the node's `inner sep`option.

Comment: Great! (1) How are the elements positioned in your code, I do not see remember picture etc? (2) Do you know if there is an overview of the available hooks somewhere? For example, if there is a shipout/foreground?

Comment: With `\put` all absolute positioning is made and `(0,0)` is the top-left page corner. `texdoc ltshipout` should take you to the documentation. The whole hook management is introduced in `texdoc lthooks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.